# Word for giving preference to the oldest child

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that refers to a system or social approach of giving the oldest child the most advantage/attention/rights. E.g.
"Why do they get to sit in the front seat"
"Because they're the oldest"
"That argument doesn't work. We don't practice ______."

I'm not looking for primogeniture, as the word I'm looking for has more to do with day to day activities than inheritance.

Comment: In your example, just "favouritism" will do.

Comment: **Primogeniture** ​
"the custom by which all of a family's property goes to the oldest son when the father dies" [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/primogeniture)

Comment: @Paul Jennings The OP's example is not about property but about the _preferential right_ of a better seat.

Comment: @MrLister - in the colonies we favor "favoritism". :-)

Comment: @MrLister although _favouritism_ works in that sentence, because it doesn't imply "_towards the older/oldest child_", it would be a stronger claim than the OP is specifically asking about (they _may_ practice giving preference towards the younger/youngest child!)

Comment: @NigelJ What is a king if not just a person with a preferential right of a better seat? ;)

Comment: @CeilingGecko But most monarchs I've seen get to sit in the _back_ seats (of cars, state coaches etc.)!

Comment: @TripeHound If the King wants shotgun, the King gets shotgun.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Seniority** is a general concept that applies to people who are (a) older or who (b) have been around for longer. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/seniority) explains:

> 1. The fact or state of being **older** or **higher** in rank or status than someone else.
> 2. A privileged position earned by reason of **longer service** or **higher rank**.

The concept is commonly applied to companies and other hierarchies, including family structures. Within a family, the eldest child may have more seniority than his or her siblings by dint of longer service or age. So in your scenario, when one person says,

> "Why do they get to sit in the front seat"
> "Because they're the oldest"

That primes a response on the basis of **seniority**, which would benefit the oldest.

> "That argument doesn't work. We don't practice **seniority**."

If you wanted to be more precise, you could even specify the kind of seniority, e.g. "sibling seniority." Here is [blogger Jules Kendall's description](https://pancakesandfrenchfries.com/2013/06/the-way-way-back/) of seating priority with her siblings while growing up; she describes the power of choice she has over her siblings as "sibling seniority":

> Later, the only child sat in the front seat in between the parents if the seat stretched out like a bench. If there was a console, they laid (or sat or twirled) in back seats like royalty on wide expanses of bonded leather or short pile upholstery. One brother, then two. My space became crowded, but as the oldest I was able to skirt the middle seat thanks to irrefutable laws of **sibling seniority**.

Comment: This is not the answer I would have chosen. On this site we don't upvote answers because seniority is practiced here.... without context, the term is confusing. "Birtherism" as a noun would make greater sense, if it meant awarding privileges to a firstborn.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you want to go that direction, how about _ageism_.

Comment: @Mary-LouA "Birtherism" means something totally different and would be out of place in this context.

Comment: @Grault I know what birtherism means, I said "**if** it meant awarding privileges to a firstborn"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I sorta agree with you, except that all of the other answers appear to be worse, to my eye.

Comment: Seniority != preference to the senior.

Answer (score 21):

You might use the term  ***birthright:***

> a particular right of possession or privilege a person has from birth, especially as an eldest son.

Comment: This is the answer that most closely fits the example. It wouldn't necessarily be applied in favor of a middle child, for example.

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, the word you are seeking appears to be obsolete. It is the use of the word 'firstborn' to express the *rights of the firstborn.*

Firstborn :

> 2. That is the right of the firstborn. Obsolete. nonce-use.

1770   O. Goldsmith Deserted Village 256   Spontaneous joys..The soul adopts, and owns their **first-born** sway.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70611?redirectedFrom=firstborn#eid)

I think you will need two words to fulfil your sentence :

> That argument doesn't work. We don't practice **firstborn preference**.

Comment: *Firstborn preference* seems an optimum compromise between exactness of meaning and understandability?

Comment: @Amos Although slightly than in your question, "_We don't favour the firstborn._" could be another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @Amos: The should have been "slightly different wording than...".

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OED entry that you're quoting. It's defining an *adjective* "firstborn"; in the quotation, "first-born sway" means "sway that is the right of the firstborn". There's no reason to think that Goldsmith would have used "first-born" in a sentence of the form "We don't practice _____".

Comment: @ruakh I disagree. The OED is giving the meaning 'the right of the firstborn' to the usage of the single word 'firstborn'.

Comment: @NigelJ: No, it's giving the definition "**That is** the right of the firstborn" (emphasis mine): "first-born sway" is "sway **that is** the right of the firstborn". You can disagree all you like, but it won't change the facts.

Comment: @ruakh I disagree with what you say. But I defend your right to say it.

Answer (score 4):

***Deference*** refers to the general concept of acceptance of another's wishes or needs ahead of the needs of another (including the self), and is commonly apparent as a social approach that references certain characteristics of the individuals within a social interaction that indicate who should defer to whom.

For example, it is *common* for a child to be expected to defer to the wishes of a parent, or for a younger child to *defer* to the eldest in certain, appropriate situations (which can include situations that are considered *socially* appropriate).

'Deference' is *not* specific to the act of a younger child acceding to the wishes or needs of an elder child, however you can refer to a younger child *deferring* to the eldest.

I would agree that the accepted answer of *seniority*, and the word *birthright* is more specific to the case of an *older* child having certain advantage, however those words also do not indicate that more *attention* should be applied, as the opposite is usually true that a *younger* child requires (and often receives) greater attention. The word 'seniority' also does not imply a *right*.

Comment: The word does not indicate who defers to whom; plus, OP talked about the environment or social system, not an arrangement among the siblings themselves.

Comment: @einpoklum. Thanks, I've qualifed/clarified my answer in response to your observations

Answer (score -1):

Primogeniture was the word used to describe the system by which the first born son of an English sovereign or any other titled person would inherit the throne or any other rank after death. The British law with respect to the throne has now been changed to agree a daughter may now inherit the throne. if she is burn before a son. With reference to your comment on my previous answer, you are correct, Pablo Straub, when giving or defining a word one's opinion is superfluous and may be misleading. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Aled Cymro. It seems you are not answering the question but giving your opinion on the situation. This is not how answers are supposed to be done. Maybe a comment in better than an answer in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Some decisions and the reasons we make to justify them are the result of prejudice or of an ideology inculcated into an impressionable young mind and thus there is no logical answer. But we ask them anyway.